# How code in program for display same image view whatever orientation?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview

I want to show same image view whatever u have mode either portrait or LAndsacpe mode.5n my case when i change my UIView then image frame in scroll layout frame don't show same image it start from image no.1 but i required same image no. when i change orientation. So for that what will i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're having problems with scroll views when the orientation changes? Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322554/clean-autorotation-transitions-in-a-paging-uiscrollview/3349927#3349927) I posted a while ago (example code included).

Comment: this method is not implement in code. because i have define ratation in app delegate file. and i have two different xib which is shown by switch controller. so for xib how i do it?