# LandscapeOrientation on start of didload method in objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation, viewdidload

I've made an iPad application,

It works fine when I load my application in portrait mode for first time, but when I load my application in landscape mode for the first time, it takes the coordinates of portrait mode only, because inside my `didLoad` method I give coordinates of portrait mode only.

Now need to give coordinates of landscape mode inside my `didLoad` method.

I tried this, inside my didLoad method

```
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfacePortraitmode ||
    interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceUpsideDown)
{
    // do this....
}
else
{
    // do this....
}
```

but I am unable to write the condition for the if/else inside my `didLoad` method.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated {
       [super viewWillAppear: animated];
       [self adjustViewtForNewOrientation: self.interfaceOrientation];
}

-(void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation duration: (NSTimeInterval) duration {
       [self adjustViewtForNewOrientation: interfaceOrientation];
}


- (void) adjustViewtForNewOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
         // Do some stuff
    } else {
         // Do some other stuff
    }
```

also call `adjustViewtForNewOrientation` in your ViewDidLaod() method,

Answer (score 3):

You can do handling as below -

```
-(void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated {
       [super viewWillAppear: animated];
       [self updateLayoutForNewOrientation: self.interfaceOrientation];
}

-(void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation duration: (NSTimeInterval) duration {
       [self updateLayoutForNewOrientation: interfaceOrientation];
}
```

and then finally custom method -

```
- (void) updateLayoutForNewOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
         // Do some stuff
    } else {
         // Do some other stuff
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I had similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8776040/1109395) with UIScrollView. I had it fixed by aligning the subviews as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3349927/1109395).

```
- (void)alignSubViews
{
    // Position all the content views at their respective page positions
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.contentViews.count * scrollView.bounds.size.width,
                                        scrollView.bounds.size.height);
    NSUInteger i = 0;
    for (UIView *v in self.contentViews) {
        v.frame = CGRectMake(i * scrollView.bounds.size.width, 0,
                             scrollView.bounds.size.width, scrollView.bounds.size.height);
        i++;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Setup subviews and then align the views.

    [self alignSubViews];
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
                                         duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
{
    [self alignSubViews];
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.currentPage * scrollView.bounds.size.width, 0);
}
```