# Adding subviews to UIScrollView in landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a view controller that starts in landscape mode with a UIScrollView in it. I try to create subviews and add them to the UIScrollView but the frame size of the views were all in portrait size.

Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.scrollView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];

    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor blueColor], nil];

    for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++) 
    {
        CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;

        UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        subview.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * colors.count, 
                                             self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of this answer: [LandscapeOrientation on start of didload method in objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775911/landscapeorientation-on-start-of-didload-method-in-objective-c)

Comment: Fix the issue by aligning the subviews on rotation as suggested in [Clean autorotation transitions in a paging UIScrollView][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322554/clean-autorotation-transitions-in-a-paging-uiscrollview

Comment: You need to change your scrollview dimensions when you rotate the device

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self.scrollView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
   NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor blueColor], nil];
   for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++)
   {
      CGRect frame = self.scrollView.bounds;
      frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * i;
      frame.origin.y = 0;
      UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
      subview.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
      [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
   }
   [self.scrollView setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];
   self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * colors.count,self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
   self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
   self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
   self.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
   self.scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
 }

- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
  {
    currentPageOffset = [self.scrollView contentOffset].x / [self.scrollView bounds].size.width;
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation))
    {
         for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
         {
            UIView *currentView = [[self.scrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:i];
            [currentView setFrame:CGRectMake((i)*currentView.frame.size.height, 0,    [self.scrollView bounds].size.height,[self.scrollView bounds].size.width)];
    }

    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.bounds.size.height *3, self.scrollView.bounds.size.width)];


     }
     else
     {
          for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
          {
              UIView *currentView = [[self.scrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:i];
              [currentView setFrame:CGRectMake((i)*currentView.frame.size.height, 0,[self.scrollView bounds].size.height,[self.scrollView bounds].size.width)];
          }

          [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.bounds.size.height * 3, self.scrollView.bounds.size.width)];        
     }
   }
   - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
     {
         [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake([self.scrollView bounds].size.width * currentPageOffset, 0.0f) animated:NO];
     }
```

You can try this code. The values used are tweakable based on your requirement. If you try to set the frame on your own with rotations make sure that you dont use the autoresizing mask or else everything can go wrong. Hope that answers to your question.